# Qgis 2.0 and conection with Postgres 9.3.2

Tags: postgresql, qgis-2

I tried conection with Qgis 2.0 with Postgres 9.3.2 but I was unable to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the [QGIS documentation](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html).

If you have a more specific question, please update your question with relevant details such as what you've already tried, what didn't work, what happened instead (including any errors) and what you are trying to do at a conceptual level (e.g. what kind of operations on what kind of vector or raster data).